# nuxtjs $refs scrollTop not move top

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using nuxtjs v2.11 ,
I just want to go to testing ref but seems it not move to testing div.

```
  <button @click="goToRefsTesting()">
      go to testing dev
  </button>


<div
  ref="testing"
  id="testing"
  >
   just testing
 </div>
```

in the methods as you expect

```
methods: {
        goToRefsTesting() {
            console.log('go to ref pls')
            this.$refs.testing.scrollTop = 0
        },
```

i got the console log message, but it still not move to testing div. any thought? is it nuxt issue or what.

Answer (score 0):

Your page needs to have enough content for `scrollTop` or `scrollIntoView` to be able to work.

Most likely there's nothing after the div, so the page cannot scroll.

Add some more content and you'll see the content move.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i found out it is not vue/nuxt problem. the container got auto scroll properties. so that is why it is not working.thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in any component without ref (but it only scrolls to top), smooth scrolling is default behavior

<button @click=scrollToTop()>Jump to top of page

```
methods: {
    scrollToTop() {
      window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
    }
  }
```